# Numbers not acting like numbers in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, numbers

Here is my code:

```
function castBurn()
{
    var cardNumber = currentCard;// == 149 (currentCard:int)
    var card1 = cardNumber - 1;// 149 - 1 = 148
    var card2 = cardNumber + 1;// 149 +1 = 150
    var card3 = cardNumber - row;// row = 23 and so on
    var card4 = cardNumber + row;

    //cardArray:Array (full of objects(Cards)
    cardArray[card1].burn = true;// card1 is recognized and flips
    cardArray[card2].burn = true;// throws a runtime error (term is unidentified)
    cardArray[card3].burn = true;// See bottom for notes
    cardArray[card4].burn = true;

    for (var j = 0; j < cardArray.length; j++)
    {// This works 
        var card = cardArray[j];
        if (card.burn == true)
        {
            if (card.wall != true)
            {
                card.flip.gotoAndPlay(2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I substitute the card1, card2, card3, card4 vars with the numbers themselves, it works great. But I need to calculate these numbers based on the 'current card'... I have done this several times before. What am I missing?... I also tried to write `var card1 = cardArray[currentCard + 1];` but that method doesn't work either. The ONLY way I get this to work is by writing `card1 = 148;`

Comment: What do you see if you look at `card2` in the debugger?

Comment: Are you sure `cardNumber` is a number, not a string? If it's a string, `+` is concatenation, not addition.

Comment: Type declarations are a good way to guarantee you're using numbers and not strings: `var cardNumber:int = currentCard;` `var card1:int = cardNumber - 1;` etc

Comment: I used var currentCard = 149;... When I added :int to the var it gave me an error, 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type int.

Comment: I know it's an int, I am trying to access an array at an index of the int

Comment: OMG! In some earlier code, when I tried to reassign 'currentCard' to 'i', I accidentally assigned it [i]. I guess I converted the int to an Array. wow. Thanks Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

AS3 is strongly typed language. Use Type declarations in your code and your compiler will tell you what is wrong.